# Elements on Upper part of WebPages goes behind the screen or Disappear from Screen while running Selenium Tests

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium web driver with Java in test automation framework of WebApplication which is portlet based using Java.My workflow is...

1. On Wizard Page-1: a container available having 2-3 input/edit boxes, some dropdown list(using Select class) and few buttons. That is like Wizard. After entering all required data on wizard of page-1. then click to Next button to navigate to Wizard Page-2.
2. On Wizard Page-2: First option is dropdown list where we use Select class i.e. selectByValue/selectByIndex etc.But during of after this action,application showed like scrolling up. But when we observed, actually it hides the first line of all webelements on Page-2.

I am sharing the screenshots for problem. Shared two images are, one is before action or real screen and second one is which hides few web element after the action.

[image]

image can be accessed: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2IDRpIvYf7SnphOVB4R1N3aTg

Comment: Can you tell which browser you are facing problem. Check whether this problem is occurring for other browsers also